# Substitute every comma outside of double quotes for a pipe

Tags: sed, regular-expression, csv

Using sed, I'd like to substitute every comma that is outside of double quotes for a pipe.

So that this line in .csv file:

```
John,Tonny,"345.3435,23",56th Street
```

Would be converted to:

```
John|Tonny|"345.3435,23"|56th Street
```

Could you help me with the regex for that?

Comment: Are you sure you're not allowed to have `\"` if a string in double quotes contains a double-quote? That would complicate matters a bit.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz If it's standard CSV, he wouldn't have `\"` but he would have `""`, as double quotes are escaped by doubling them so the format doesn't have another special character to escape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `sed` supports the `-E` option (`-r` in some implementations):

```
sed -Ee :1 -e 's/^(([^",]|"[^"]*")*),/\1|/;t1' < file
```

The

```
:label
   s/pattern/replacement/
t label
```

Is a very common `sed` idiom. It keeps doing the same substitution in a loop as long as it's successful.

Here, we're substituting the leading part of the line made of 0 or more quoted strings or characters other that `"` and `,` (captured in `\1`)  followed by a `,` with that `\1` capture and a `|`, so on your sample that means:

- `John,Tonny,"345.3435,23",56th Street` -> `John|Tonny,"345.3435,23",56th Street`
- `John|Tonny,"345.3435,23",56th Street` -> `John|Tonny|"345.3435,23",56th Street`
- `John|Tonny|"345.3435,23",56th Street` -> `John|Tonny|"345.3435,23"|56th Street`
- and we stop here as the pattern doesn't match any more on that.

With `perl`, you could do it with one substitution with the `g` flag with:

```
perl -pe 's{("[^"]*"|[^",]+)|,}{$1 // "|"}ge'
```

Here, assuming quotes are balanced in the input, the pattern would match all the input, breaking it up in either:

- quoted string
- sequences of characters other than `,` or `"`
- a comma

And only when the matched string is a comma (when `$1` is not defined in the replacement part), replace it with a `|`.

Comment: is the loop needed here? `sed -E 's/("[^"]+"|[^,]+),/\1|/g'` works for me on GNU sed..

Comment: @Sundeep, yours wouldn't work on an input like `,foo` or `",foo"` or `"x",",y"`

Comment: @Sundeep, or `"a,b"` or `a,"b,c"` or `a,,b`

Comment: @Stéphane Could you explain the meaning of :1 in your command?

Comment: @Quentin, see edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks. And could you also tell me if there's a simple perl command to edit a file (used as input) in place? The -i option doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's some impressive corner cases to think of and elegant perl solution (I was trying different ways and gave up)... @Quentin, `perl -i -pe ...` should work, could you elaborate the issue? did you get an error?

Answer (score 14):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvformat -D '|' file.csv
John|Tonny|345.3435,23|56th Street
```

The tools in csvkit knows how to handle the intricacies of CVS files, and here we're using `csvformat` to replace the delimiting commas with `|` correctly.  The output fields will be quoted as needed.

Example:

```
$ cat file.csv
John,Tonny,"345.3435,23",56th Street
The | factory,Ltd.,"0,0",meep meep

$ csvformat -D '|' file.csv
John|Tonny|345.3435,23|56th Street
"The | factory"|Ltd.|0,0|meep meep
```

Answer (score 3):

With perl

```
perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN { $p = Text::CSV->new() } 
  print join "|", $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)
' file.csv
John|Tonny|345.3435,23|56th Street
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '{gsub(/,/,"|"); printf("%s", $0 RT)}' RS='"[^"]*"' input.txt
```

or the same, but another way:

```
gawk -F, '{$1=$1; printf("%s", $0 RT)}' RS='"[^"]*"' OFS='|' input.txt
```

**Input**

```
John,Tonny,"345.3435,23",56th Street
one,"two,three",four,five,"six,stub,seven",eight,nine
one,"two,three",four,five,"six,stub,seven",eight,nine,"ten,eleven,twelve"
```

**Output**

```
John|Tonny|"345.3435,23"|56th Street
one|"two,three"|four|five|"six,stub,seven"|eight|nine
one|"two,three"|four|five|"six,stub,seven"|eight|nine|"ten,eleven,twelve"
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python and `csv` module:

```py
import csv,sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    csvr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in csvr:
        dup = map( lambda x: '"' + x + '"' if ',' in x else x, line )
        print('|'.join(dup))
```

Works as so:

```
$ python3 csvfile.py  input.csv 
John|Tonny|"345.3435,23"|56th Street
John|Doe|"123.456,25"|26th Street
Jane|Doe|"987.654,52"|15th Street
```